# Command line options for KiTTy in windows 10

Tags: windows, kitty

I have been trying to execute kitty_nocompress.exe invoking the -config option with no success. I am using the command line from Windows 10. The KiTTY version I am using is 0.64.0.1.

I have tried the following:

```
    kitty_nocompress -config <configuration file>
    kitty_nocompress -c <configuration file>
```

These give me the error messages "Unknown option 'config'" and "Unknown option '-c'" respectively.

```
    kitty_nocompress /config <configuration file>
    kitty_nocompress /c <configuration file>
```

These give me the error message "Unable to open connection to /config. Host does not exist" and "Unable to open connection to /c. Host does not exist" respectively.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer by researching my work from years ago before I retired.  It is amazing how much you forget in 5 years.

Anyway, this code does what I want.

```
    C:\KiTTY\kitty_nocompress.exe -load <configuration file>
```

The configuration file contains a script that will be executed upon logging into remote UNIX server.